# Count records in each month using Month(dateField) in SQL

Tags: sql, date, datetime, datetime-format, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I have a large table containing c650,000 records. They are individuals with email addresses and one of the fields is 'dateOfApplication'. I have been asked for a breakdown of how many people signed up in each month.

I'd like the results to look something like

```
Month     Year     Total 
1         2017     50763
2         2017     34725
```

And have made a target table in this format to put the results in. I've been able to use Month(dateOfApplication) to get the month component of the date using

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [UG_Master]
WHERE MONTH([UG_Master].dateOfApplication) = '6') as Total
```

To return particular months, but don't really know how to get one row for each month it finds.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but don't really know how to get one row for each month it finds.

You can use `GROUP BY`  :

```
SELECT MONTH([UG_Master].dateOfApplication), COUNT(1) 
FROM [UG_Master]
GROUP BY MONTH([UG_Master].dateOfApplication);
```

If you want `year` wise `month`s then include year also :

```
SELECT YEAR([UG_Master].dateOfApplication), MONTH([UG_Master].dateOfApplication), COUNT(1) 
FROM [UG_Master]
GROUP BY YEAR([UG_Master].dateOfApplication), MONTH([UG_Master].dateOfApplication);
```

Comment: what if they have records from previous years, it's seemed to me like you also need to group by the year column right?

Comment: Wonderful - worked perfectly, thanks. I'd forgotten about Group By, but still wasn't on the right lines until this! Thanks.